# AngularJS ngMap parameters on-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm attempting to use this Angular Google map directive http://ngmap.github.io/.
I would like to add a click event to each marker, which calls a function in the controller, passing through the marker's id. When I print out the id in the console, I get "hq {latLng: wf, ub: undefined, pixel: undefined, xa: undefined}", which isn't the id.
My HTML is

```
<map center="{{map.center.latitude}},{{map.center.longitude}}" zoom="{{map.zoom}}">

                    <marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" position="{{marker.latitude}}, {{marker.longitude}}" icon="{{marker.icon}}" id="{{marker.id}}" on-click="goAnchor(marker.id)"></marker>
                </map>
```

My controller code:

```
$scope.goAnchor = function (id) {
            console.log(id);
            gotoAnchor(id);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

"this" returns the marker clicked by you

```
$scope.goAnchor = function (event) {
 console.log(this.id);
 gotoAnchor(this.id);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" position="{{marker.latitude}},{{marker.longitude}}" icon="{{marker.icon}}" id="{{marker.id}}" on-click="goAnchor($event)"></marker>
```

Comment: how do you access scope variable inside such callback functions? I get it as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in function

```
$scope.goAnchor = function (event) {
   console.log(event.target.attributes.id.value);
   gotoAnchor(event.target.attributes.id.value);
};
```

**Mark Up**

```
<marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" position="{{marker.latitude}}, {{marker.longitude}}" icon="{{marker.icon}}" id="{{marker.id}}" on-click="goAnchor($event)"></marker>
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but the documentation shows on-click. http://ngmap.github.io/events.html#
I tried ng-click and that doesn't even call the controller, on-click does.

Comment: I never see `on-click`. But I guess to pass the function's value in controller's `$scope` we need to use it's predefined directives.

Comment: Still no luck. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Comment: @user1024941 My Bad. Please check my edited answer. I forgot to pass `$event` in `on-click`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88064/discussion-between-vineet-and-user1024941).

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to get Latitude and Longitude of clicked marker.

```
 <ng-map zoom="12" center="{{vm.geoCenterLoc}}" style="height:500px">
            <marker ng-repeat="p in vm.positions"
                    position="{{p.pos}}"
                    data="{{data[$index]}}"
                    on-click="myFunc($event)";
                    title="pos: {{p.pos}}"></marker>
   </ng-map>
```

Javascript(on my controller):

```
$scope.myFunc = function (evt) {

            markerPosObj = {
                pos: [this.getPosition().lat(), this.getPosition().lng()]
            };
            markerPos = [];
            markerPos.push(markerPosObj);
            console.log('this marker', markerPos);
        }
```